# unable to filter/query box api response?

Tags: api, postman, box-api, box, uipath-studio

I am working on filtering of box folder for that I have tried to filter box folder using query (?q=name=folder name) but using this I am unable to get required filtered/queried result.

Using query based on "NAME" or "ID" parameter I am trying to get particular file/folder details, But I am unable to get the filtered  result.

Comment: can you at least link the API you're using?

Comment: https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/132806349379/items/?q=name=CIP

Comment: I mean the documentation of that endpoint